# Change End Point in Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I've created a Maven based Java project that has two web service clients defined.  I used Netbeans web service wizard to add them to the project.

Unfortunately the URL of the WSDL has changed to a different IP address.  I'm wondering how you go about reconfiguring an existing Java project to use a new URL for a web service.  To me this should be a configuration value.

I did a search for the IP address in the project and it was found in around 6 different locations.  Is there one place I can make the change?  Or do I need to do a find and replace?

Comment: When you say you found it "in the project", where specifically? Is it in a bunch of properties files? Hardcoded all over the place?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the URL in the WSDL does not matter because you can change the endpoint URL in your code (which you can read in from a properties or XML file).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the endpoint address:

```
final WeatherService service = new WeatherService();
Weather port = service.getWeatherPort();
final BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
final Map<String, Object> requestContext = getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointAddress);
```

Where `endpointAddress` is the new address.